# Python: Create Timerseries Dummy Variable based on DateTime List

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, match, conditional-statements

I have two `dataframes.` `my_index` is containing the data for further analysis based on minute data `my_index['TIME']` in format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` (total length 100.000 rows).
The other dataframe `release_plain`contains specific datetimes (same Time format) within the timespan of the other one (length 70). Both DateTimes are string format

Now I want to match the dates of `release_plain` against those with `my_index` and when there is a match write a 1 in a new column `my_index['Dummy']` for a range 5 mins before and after the match (so in total eleven 1ns).

What I have so far:

```
release_plain = pd.read_csv(infile)
my_index = pd.read_csv(index_file)

datetime = release_plain['Date'].astype(str) + ' ' + release_plain['Time'].astype(str)
list_datetime = list(datetime)


for date_of_interest in list_datetime:
    if my_index.loc[my_index['TIME']==date_of_interest]:
        my_index['Dummy'] == 1
    else:
        my_index['Dummy'] == 0
```

But this returns:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

And moreover, from what I have this will only create 1 Dummy for the specific DateTime but not the Dummy Range 5 mins before and after the Event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if my_index.loc[my_index['TIME']==date_of_interest]`

Your brackets here don't seem to make sense, you are passing an evaluation as a `key` pretty much that reads `if my_index.loc[True]:` or `if my_index.loc[False]` not sure if you have `keys` that are `True` and `False` but I'm expecting that you don't, perhaps you meant this:

`if my_index.loc[my_index['TIME']] == date_of_interest`